# Round up and compare indices Python

Tags: python, datetime, indexing

I have multiple csv files with unix timestamps that I use as DateTimeIndexes, which I would like to compare.

Example of a single file:

```
Unixtime           Value     
1525328729150.00   15.06
1525328729943.00   16.05
1525328730741.00   16.32
1525328731536.00   16.35
1525328732335.00   16.87
1525328733131.00   16.99
1525328733932.00   17.45
1525328734731.00   17.65
```

Currently I am using the following (snippet) to set the DatetimeIndex (works flawlessly):

```
data[i] = pd.read_csv(temp_file_name, index_col=' Time_Created')
data[i].index = pd.to_datetime(data[i].index, unit='ns')
```

However, there are several problems when I want to compare the values of two different files at a specific time:

1. The times in the files dont exactly match up. It could be 01:443 seconds in one file and 01:247 in the other one.
2. Rounding up to either a second or 500ms causes problems where indices might get skipped or duplicated. Rounding to 500ms could round 01:443 to 01:500, but 01:247 to 01:000.

I have tried several approaches:

1. Rounding up the int64 integers
2. Rounding up the DatetimeIndex

So far tried out using

```
np.round(data[i].index.astype(np.int64), -13).astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

or

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(((data[i].index.asi8/(1e13*60)).round()*1e13*60)
.astype(np.int64)).values
```

or

```
ns1min=1*60*1000000000   # 1 minute in nanoseconds 
pd.to_datetime(((data[i].index.astype(np.int64) // ns1min + 1 ) * ns1min))
```

or

```
pandas.DatetimeIndex.round
```

But none seem to either work or provide me with the solution that I need, which is the subtraction of two values at (roughly) the same time.
What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using

```
round_amount = 1*1*1000000000
data[i].index = pd.DatetimeIndex(((data[i].index.asi8/(round_amount)).round()*round_amount).astype(np.int64))
```

Which rounds the DatetimeIndex to the nearest second.